# LINQ - select by property in object in list within object

Tags: c#

I have a list of custom objects called LanguageItem. This LanguageItem contains a list of items called 'Tag'. Each Tag has an ID.

Now I've read up on LINQ but all the examples (and I have read around on this site and others before asking my question) seem to focus on a property within the object of the list you are searching.

So let's say I have a Tag, and so I have my Tag ID. What I want is a list of LanguageItems which contain a Tag with that ID.

I've had a few attempts, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere so I'm turning to you guys.

Comment: `items.Where(li => li.Tag.Any(t => t.ID == [value]))`

Answer (score 5):

See if this code helps you.

```
public IEnumerable<LanguageItem> GetItemsByTagID(string targetID)
{
    var result = LanguageItems.Where(lItem => lItem.Tags.Any(tagItem => tagItem.ID == targetID));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I'd like to ask... I can't seem to get it to be an ObservableCollection (I'm using WPF so I rather need one) without using the 'new' keyword. Somehow it feels bad to do this, since I will be using 'new' on every search. Am I just being paranoid?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
var FoundLanguageItems = LanguageList.Where(ThisLang => ThisLang.Tags.SingleOrDefault(ThisTag => ThisTag.id == SearchId) != null);
```

This basically nests two LINQ queries.  The inner query is this.

```
ThisLang.Tags.SingleOrDefault(ThisTag => ThisTag.id == SearchId)
```

That means, given a Language object named ThisLang, give me one Tag object that has the search tag id, or give me null if there are no tags objects in ThisLang.Tags that have that search id.

**If this inner query returns null, it means that the language had no tags with that id.**

The outer query is

```
LanguageList.Where(ThisLanguage => INNER_QUERY != null)
```

That means, from LanguageList, give me the languages where that INNER_QUERY did not return a null, meaning, where that inner query found at least one matching tag and so it returned a NOT_NULL value.

Comment: This will return Tags and not ListLanguageItems. :)

Comment: @Paul - that is not true.  This returns the subset from languagelist that fits the select statement.  You are not doing a select on tags, you are doing a select on the original list of languages.

Comment: @Agapwlesu: I am wrong anyway. Nevertheless I usually use Select from System.Linq as a mapping function. I would assume, that you get a list of booleans. What am I missing?

Comment: @Paul - if you start with a list of objects, in this case a list of languages `LanguageList`, and you do `LanguageList.Select(...)` The result is going to be a list of languages.  The lambda expression inside the parenthesis should return a boolean that says, for each element in the starting list, do we include it in the results list or not.

Comment: But, Leonardo's answer, using Any for the inner query, is better.

Comment: I think you're wrong. Check out this c# fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7sD5Qf. There is a difference between `Select` and `Where`.

Comment: @Paul - I think you're right.  Can't believe I made such a rookie mistake.  Meant to put `Where` instead of `Select`.